# Clear button not changing state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I have a clear button that should be visible if the `date` and `time` fields are filled and not visible if they are empty. The logic part works but the state does not change and if both the `textfields` are filled the checkbox doesn't appear. I can't use the default suffix icon as both the textfields are wrapped within a gesture detector.

```
class TodoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? todoIndex;
  final int? arrayIndex;

  const TodoScreen({Key? key, this.todoIndex, this.arrayIndex})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TodoScreen> createState() => _TodoScreenState();


class _TodoScreenState extends State<TodoScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String date = '';
    String? time = '';

    if (widget.todoIndex != null) {
      date = arrayController
          .arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].date!;
      time = arrayController
          .arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].time;
    }

    TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController(text: date);
    TextEditingController _timeController = TextEditingController(text: time);

    late String _setTime, _setDate;
    late String _hour, _minute, _time;
    late String dateTime;
    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay(
        hour: (TimeOfDay.now().minute > 55)
            ? TimeOfDay.now().hour + 1
            : TimeOfDay.now().hour,
        minute: (TimeOfDay.now().minute > 55) ? 0 : TimeOfDay.now().minute + 5);

    Future<DateTime?> _selectDate() => showDatePicker(
        builder: (context, child) {
          return datePickerTheme(child);
        },
        initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
        firstDate: DateTime.now(),
        lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5));

    Future<TimeOfDay?> _selectTime() => showTimePicker(
        builder: (context, child) {
          return timePickerTheme(child);
        },
        context: context,
        initialTime: selectedTime,
        initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input);

    Future _pickDateTime() async {
      DateTime? date = await _selectDate();
      if (date == null) return;
      if (date != null) {
        selectedDate = date;
        _dateController.text = DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(selectedDate);
      }
      TimeOfDay? time = await _selectTime();
      if (time == null) {
        _timeController.text = formatDate(
            DateTime(
                DateTime.now().year,
                DateTime.now().day,
                DateTime.now().month,
                DateTime.now().hour,
                DateTime.now().minute + 5),
            [hh, ':', nn, " ", am]).toString();
      }
      if (time != null) {
        selectedTime = time;
        _hour = selectedTime.hour.toString();
        _minute = selectedTime.minute.toString();
        _time = _hour + ' : ' + _minute;
        _timeController.text = _time;
        _timeController.text = formatDate(
            DateTime(2019, 08, 1, selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute),
            [hh, ':', nn, " ", am]).toString();
      }
    }

    bool visible =
        (_dateController.text.isEmpty && _timeController.text.isEmpty)
            ? false
            : true;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  await _pickDateTime();
                  visible = true;
                },
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 15.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: tertiaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: TextField(
                                enabled: false,
                                controller: _dateController,
                                onChanged: (String val) {
                                  _setDate = val;
                                },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Date",
                                    hintStyle: hintTextStyle,
                                    border: InputBorder.none),
                                style: todoScreenStyle,
                              ),
                            ),
                            visible
                                ? IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      _dateController.clear();
                                      _timeController.clear();
                                      visible = false;
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.close,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ))
                                : Container()
                          ],
                        ),
                        primaryDivider,
                        TextField(
                          onChanged: (String val) {
                            _setTime = val;
                          },
                          enabled: false,
                          controller: _timeController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Time",
                              hintStyle: hintTextStyle,
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                          style: todoScreenStyle,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}}
```

If the code doesn't fully make sense it's because I removed some of the irrelevant code that do not add any real value to the question

[Full code on Github](https://github.com/Rohith-JN/Tasks-Android/blob/main/lib/View/TodoScreen.dart)

Comment: try manhtuan21's post, if fails consider simplifying the snippet .


More about [/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move all your `TextEditController` outside of build method, it should be initialized in the `initState` method, like this :

```
  late TextEditingController _dateController;
  late TextEditingController _timeController;
  late TextEditingController titleEditingController;
  late TextEditingController detailEditingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    String title = '';
    String detail = '';
    String date = '';
    String? time = '';

    if (widget.todoIndex != null) {
      title = arrayController.arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].title ?? '';
      detail = arrayController.arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].details ?? '';
      date = arrayController.arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].date!;
      time = arrayController.arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].time;
    }

    _dateController = TextEditingController(text: date);
    _timeController = TextEditingController(text: time);
    titleEditingController = TextEditingController(text: title);
    detailEditingController = TextEditingController(text: detail);
  }
```

Then, change your onPressed function:

```
 onPressed: () {
   _dateController.clear();
   _timeController.clear();
   setState(() {});
 },
```

For your question about `CheckBox`, you don't need a `StreamBuilder` for that, just put your `CheckBox` like this:

```
Checkbox(
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        checkColor: Colors.white,
        activeColor: primaryColor,
        value: done,
        side: Theme.of(context)
            .checkboxTheme
            .side,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            done = value;
          });
        })
```

And of cource, try to move your done variable outside build method too:

```
  late bool done;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    done =
    (widget.todoIndex == null) ? false : arrayController.arrays[widget.arrayIndex!].todos![widget.todoIndex!].done!;
  }
```

Comment: It worked, but can you explain why the textEditingControllers were to be placed outside of the build method?

Comment: Because build method can be run many time depend on state change (eg: parent of this widget change, this widget call setState itseft, ...). Something like TextEditController should only be initialized single time in initState, if you put it inside build method, everytime you setState, it will create a new controller

Comment: If I could give you another advise, you should move all your pick time function out of build method too

Comment: Ok, should I also move the done variable out of the build method as its state changes because of the setState

Comment: Everything works perfectly now but not sure how to implement the checkbox variable outside of the build method as I am not able to access it

Comment: what do you mean checkbox? I don't see any CheckBox widget in your code

Comment: I didn’t add it in the question, but it’s there on github

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answered two questions